# Run script in specified width only, How?

Tags: javascript, resize

Probably really simple but I'm new to JavaScript. All I want to do is only let the scrip bellow run when the window width is greater than 768. If bellow 768 I don't want the code to work. Also I want it to sort of reload when the window is adjusted so if the browser changes width for what ever reason I want the page to work how it was designed to in that width.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logowhite.png'); 
} else {
    $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logodark.png');      
}});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the window width with `$(window).width()`. Then you do a simple conditional:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logowhite.png'); 
    } else {
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logodark.png');      
    }});
}
```

Read more: https://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: thanks this works, is there a way to get this to check when the window is resized. At the moment it works perfectly as it seems checks on load of page and then decides what to do with the logo. I would also like it to change the logo when the window changes width once the page has loaded not just on load.

Comment: Yes, you can put everything inside this: `$(window).resize(function() {});`. Every time the window resize, the function will be called. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xfev9ehL/

Answer (score 0):

Use screen width http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp
on that function use an if and check the width of screen.
Example

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(screen.width<=768){
      if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logowhite.png'); 
      } else {
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logodark.png');
      }      
    }});
```